# One line if/else condition in linux shell scripting

Tags: linux, shell, if-statement

I would like to have the equivelant of the following in a one line if/else condition.

```
$maxline=`cat journald.conf | grep "#SystemMaxUse="`
if [ $maxline == "#SystemMaxUse=" ]
then
    sed 's/\#SystemMaxUse=/SystemMaxUse=50M/g' journald.conf > journald.conf2
    mv journald.conf2 journald.conf;
else
    echo "This file has been edited. You'll need to do it manually."
fi
```

I'm attempting to put this into a one line command. So far I've gotten it all but the else portion of the command. Here's what I have so far...

```
maxline=`cat journald.conf | grep "#SystemMaxUse="` && if [ $maxline == "#SystemMaxUse=" ]; then sed 's/\#SystemMaxUse=/SystemMaxUse=50M/g' journald.conf > journald.conf2 && mv journald.conf2 journald.conf; fi
```

So how can I include the else portion of the above code into my command? Thank you for your help in advance.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

It looks as if you were on the right track. You just need to add the else statement after the ";" following the "then" statement. Also I would split the first line from the second line with a semicolon instead of joining it with `&&`.

```bash
maxline='cat journald.conf | grep "#SystemMaxUse="'; if [ $maxline == "#SystemMaxUse=" ]; then sed 's/\#SystemMaxUse=/SystemMaxUse=50M/g' journald.conf > journald.conf2 && mv journald.conf2 journald.conf; else echo "This file has been edited. You'll need to do it manually."; fi
```

Also in your original script, when declaring maxline you used back-ticks "`" instead of single quotes "'" which might cause problems.

Comment: using single quotes breaks the code; what you really want in order to be clear is double quotes and a subshell: `$maxline="$(cat journald.conf | grep '#SystemMaxUse=')"`

Answer (score 70):

To summarize the other answers, for general use:

#### Multi-line *if...then* statement

```
if [ foo ]; then
    a; b
elif [ bar ]; then
    c; d
else
    e; f
fi
```

#### Single-line version

`if [ foo ]; then a && b; elif [ bar ]; c && d; else e && f; fi`

#### Using the OR operator

`( foo && a && b ) || ( bar && c && d ) || e && f;`

#### Notes

Remember that the AND and OR operators evaluate whether or not the result code of the previous operation was equal to true/success (`0`). So if a custom function returns something else (or nothing at all), you may run into problems with the AND/OR shorthand. In such cases, you may want to replace something like `( a && b )` with `( [ a == 'EXPECTEDRESULT' ] && b )`, etc.

Also note that `(` and `[` are technically commands, so whitespace is required around them.

Instead of a group of `&&` statements like `then a && b; else`, you could also run statements in a subshell like `then $( a; b ); else`, though this is less efficient. The same is true for doing something like `result1=$( foo; a; b ); result2=$( bar; c; d ); [ "$result1" -o "$result2" ]` instead of `( foo && a && b ) || ( bar && c && d )`. Though at that point you'd be getting more into less-compact, multi-line stuff anyway.

Comment: The two single line versions are completely different from the original Multiline.

Comment: This is wrong for zsh: "( and [ are technically commands, so whitespace is required around them."    Try (false && true)||echo 'hi'

Answer (score 8):

It's not a direct answer to the question but you could just use the OR-operator

```
( grep "#SystemMaxUse=" journald.conf > /dev/null && sed -i 's/\#SystemMaxUse=/SystemMaxUse=50M/g' journald.conf ) || echo "This file has been edited. You'll need to do it manually."
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use like bellow:

`(( var0 = var1<98?9:21 ))`

the same as

```sh
if [ "$var1" -lt 98 ]; then
   var0=9
else
   var0=21
fi
```

extends

```
condition?result-if-true:result-if-false
```

I found the interested thing on the book "Advanced Bash-Scripting Guide"

Answer (score 2):

I am building a script to see whether my **multiline shell script** is valid since I need to verify whether a Linux directory exists in my situation.

```
!/bin/sh
if [ -d "/var/www/html/" ] 
then
   echo "html Directory exists"
else
  echo "html Directory not exist"
  exit 1
fi
```

You must adhere to this syntactic structure if you wish to create the same sort of script or condition on a **single line**.

```
if [ -d "/var/www/html/" ]; then echo "html Directory exists"; else echo "html Directory not exist "; fi
```

Answer (score 1):

The others answered your question, but not your specific situation. You've got cat going into grep going into a variable before we even get to the question; what you're really asking is 'how to conditionally edit a file'.

You could do this all in sed, either with some bash:

`sed -n '/^#SystemMaxUse=$/Q1' journald.conf && echo "This file has been edited. You'll need to do it manually." || sed -i 's/^#\(SystemMaxUse=\)$/\150M/' journald.conf`

or no bash:

`sed -ni journald.conf -e 'H;${x;s/^#\(SystemMaxUse=\)$/\150M/m;ta;s/\n\(.*\)/\1/p;s/.*/This file has been edited. You'll need to do it manually./;w /dev/stdout' -e 'q;:a;s/\n\(.*\)/\1/p}'`

but for editing files, vim is really the tool to reach for:

`vim journald.conf -c 'norm /^#SystemMaxUse=$^MxA50M^[ZZ' -c '!echo "This file has been edited. You’ll need to do it manually."' -c q`

which will make the change if it finds a line with `#SystemMaxUse=` on its own, or it will say

```
This file has been edited. You’ll need to do it manually. 

Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

and exit when they type any key. note that ^M and ^[ are enter and escape, and that U+2019 is used as the apostrophe.

Answer (score -1):

I recently saw the following.
example,
if you are not root make $var with a value

```
[[ $(id -u) -ne 0 ]] && var='you are not root user'
```

Comment: I don't see in what respect this answer is related to the question. There is nothing related to the uid in the question.